# How to wait for async to finish

Tags: f#, asynchronous

I would like to run some async workflow, then wait for it to finish before printing some results, example:

```
let dowork n =
    async {
        do printfn "work %d" n
    }

let creatework() =
    async {
        for x in [1..5] do
            Async.Start(dowork x)
    }

Async.RunSynchronously(creatework())    
printfn "finished"
```

when I run this, I want all the dowork calls to finish before printing "finished". However I get results like this:

work 2
work 3
work 4
work 5
finished
work 1

I have tried removing async from creatework() but "finished" is printed before the async workflows are run.

In the real dowork, the program performs some IO, so I want to wait for the slowest one to finish before continuing.

Comment: You could keep track of how many are completed and once they're all completed print finished. However there is probably a better approach I just can't come up with it atm.

Comment: Isn't waiting for async to finish sort of an oxymoron?

Comment: If the question were "get notification of when all async has finished" would it still be oxymoron?

Comment: You could make a counter that every async operation increments, and you check it in every async operation, when it hits a certain number it will fire off a different function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well answering my own question seems lame, but this seems to work. Someone come up with something better so I can award them the answer :)

```
let dowork n =
    async {
        do printfn "work %d" n
    }

let creatework() =
    [1..5] |> Seq.map dowork |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously

creatework()    
printfn "finished"
```

It gives various output, but "finished" so far is always last...

Comment: This is the right answer.  Your original code of calling `Async.Start` inside an async block was very non-idiomatic.  `Async.Parallel` is the right way to do fork-join parallelism.

Comment: Tiny refactoring: Rather than `Seq.map (fun x -> dowork x)` you could just do `Seq.map dowork`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it's convenient to use MailboxProcessor to make sure that all side-effects (e.g. printfn) happen on the same thread.  Use MailboxProcessor.PostAndReply(singleResult) to funnel work results (be it just the strings to print) into the same synchronization context, and provide for another message type that returns aggregate values.  One could use a union for types of these messages.